# Converting ArrayList into TreeSet

Tags: java, collections

I have an `ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>` which I need to convert into `TreeSet<Card>`. For this purpose I do:

```
new TreeSet<Card>(cards)
```

After all I have a size of the `TreeSet` equal to 1. The `Card` class implements `Comparable` interface. What I'm doing wrong or not doing?

Answer (score 7):

If all of the `Card`s in the `ArrayList` evaluate to equal using the provided `Comparable` interface (i.e. `compare` always returns `0`) then you will end up with just one entry in your `TreeSet`.

Comment: This solution works. Check this operation `Card.compareTo(Card card)`

Answer (score 2):

They implement Comparable, but how?
In a TreeSet, elements for which a.compareTo(b) returns 0, only the first is added.

Comment: More likely only the *last* will be retained but that is just pedantry on my part.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon just for pedantry, I tried:
        Long a = Long.valueOf(123456789012345L);
        Long b = Long.valueOf(123456789012345L);
        assertNotSame(a,b);
        TreeSet<Long> s = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(a,b));
        assertEquals(1, s.size());
        assertSame(a,s.first());

Answer (score -1):

**Easiest way to convert a List to a Set? - Java**

```
Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<Foo>(myList);

TreeSet tSet = new TreeSet(myList);
```

Comment: it's about a Treeset, not a HashSet.

Comment: Pass the ArrayList to Treeset. There is a constructor in Treeset that accept Collection.